# Combination of all rows in two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, for example with shape `(3,2)` and the other with shape `(10,7)`. I want all combinations of the two arrays such that I end up with a 9 column array. In other words, I want all combinations of each row of the first array with the rows of the second array.

How can I do this? I am not using meshgrid correctly as far as I can tell.

Based on previous posts, I was under the impression that

```
a1 = np.zeros((10,7))
a2 = np.zeros((3,2))
r = np.array(np.meshgrid(a1, a2)).T.reshape(-1, a1.shape[1] + a2.shape[1])
```

would work, but that gives me dimensions of (84,10).

Comment: What's the shape of expected output array?

Comment: It would be `(30,9)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Approach #1

With focus on performance here's one approach with `array-initialization` and `element-broadcasting` for assignments -

```
m1,n1 = a1.shape
m2,n2 = a2.shape
out = np.zeros((m1,m2,n1+n2),dtype=int)
out[:,:,:n1] = a1[:,None,:]
out[:,:,n1:] = a2
out.shape = (m1*m2,-1)
```

#### Explanation :

The trick lies in the two steps :

```
out[:,:,:n1] = a1[:,None,:]
out[:,:,n1:] = a2
```

**Step #1 :**

```
In [227]: np.random.seed(0)

In [228]: a1 = np.random.randint(1,9,(3,2))

In [229]: a2 = np.random.randint(1,9,(2,7))

In [230]: m1,n1 = a1.shape
     ...: m2,n2 = a2.shape
     ...: out = np.zeros((m1,m2,n1+n2),dtype=int)
     ...: 

In [231]: out[:,:,:n1] = a1[:,None,:]

In [232]: out[:,:,:n1]
Out[232]: 
array([[[5, 8],
        [5, 8]],

       [[6, 1],
        [6, 1]],

       [[4, 4],
        [4, 4]]])

In [233]: a1[:,None,:]
Out[233]: 
array([[[5, 8]],

       [[6, 1]],

       [[4, 4]]])
```

So, basically we are assigning the elements of `a1` keeping the first axis aligned with the corresponding one of the output, while letting the elements along the second axis of the output array being filled in a broadcasted manner corresponding to the `newaxis` being added for `a1` along that axis. This is the crux here and brings about performance because we are not allocating extra memory space, which we would need otherwise with explicit repeating/tiling methods.

**Step #2 :**

```
In [237]: out[:,:,n1:] = a2

In [238]: out[:,:,n1:]
Out[238]: 
array([[[4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5],
        [8, 7, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2]],

       [[4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5],
        [8, 7, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2]],

       [[4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5],
        [8, 7, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2]]])

In [239]: a2
Out[239]: 
array([[4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5],
       [8, 7, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2]])
```

Here, we are basically broadcasting that *block* `a2`  along the first axis of the output array without explicitly making repeated copies.

Sample input, output for completeness -

```
In [242]: a1
Out[242]: 
array([[5, 8],
       [6, 1],
       [4, 4]])

In [243]: a2
Out[243]: 
array([[4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5],
       [8, 7, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2]])

In [244]: out
Out[244]: 
array([[[5, 8, 4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5],
        [5, 8, 8, 7, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2]],

       [[6, 1, 4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5],
        [6, 1, 8, 7, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2]],

       [[4, 4, 4, 8, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5],
        [4, 4, 8, 7, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2]]])
```

### Approach #2

Another with `tiling/repeating` -

```
parte1 = np.repeat(a1[:,None,:],m2,axis=0).reshape(-1,m2)
parte2 = np.repeat(a2[None],m1,axis=0).reshape(-1,n2)
out = np.c_[parte1, parte2]
```

Comment: Your answers are very elegant, but also abstract. It would help a lot if you add some explanation to it.

Comment: @Chiel Tried my best to explain. Hope this will help the readers.

Comment: Every time I read your answers I'm amazed :)

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `np.tile` and `np.repeat` :

```
a1 = np.arange(20).reshape(5,4)
a2 = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

res=hstack((np.tile(a1,(len(a2),1)),np.repeat(a2,len(a1),0)))

# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  1],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  0,  1],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15,  0,  1],
#        [16, 17, 18, 19,  0,  1],
#        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  2,  3],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11,  2,  3],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15,  2,  3],
#        [16, 17, 18, 19,  2,  3],
#        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  4,  5],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11,  4,  5],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15,  4,  5],
#        [16, 17, 18, 19,  4,  5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

`meshgrid` can be used, but indirectly, generating row indexing:

```
In [796]: A = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
In [797]: B = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)*10    # reduced size
```

Mixed indexing of the rows of the 2 arrays:

```
In [798]: idx=np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(4),indexing='ij')
In [799]: idx
Out[799]: 
[array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]), 
 array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]])]
```

This replicates rows of `A` several times; similarly for `B`:

```
In [800]: A[idx[0],:]
Out[800]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 3],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 3],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [4, 5],
        [4, 5],
        [4, 5]]])
```

Now concatenate these on the last dimension,  producing a (3,4,5) array.  Finally reshape to (12,5):

```
In [802]: np.concatenate((A[idx[0],:],B[idx[1],:]), axis=-1).reshape(12,5)
Out[802]: 
array([[  0,   1,   0,  10,  20],
       [  0,   1,  30,  40,  50],
       [  0,   1,  60,  70,  80],
       [  0,   1,  90, 100, 110],
       [  2,   3,   0,  10,  20],
       [  2,   3,  30,  40,  50],
       [  2,   3,  60,  70,  80],
       [  2,   3,  90, 100, 110],
       [  4,   5,   0,  10,  20],
       [  4,   5,  30,  40,  50],
       [  4,   5,  60,  70,  80],
       [  4,   5,  90, 100, 110]])
```